# Is there a norm on ${\Bbb R}^{\Bbb N}$

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $E={\Bbb R}^{\Bbb N}$ be the real vector space of real sequences.

1) Is there a norm on $E$?

2) Is there a norm $N$ on $E$ such that the restriction of $N$ to $\ell^2$ is finer than the standard norm $N_2$ of $\ell^2$ ?

Comment: Indeed, there is.

Comment: I think you need the sequences to be bounded for this to work.

Comment: Sure, and more than one. Any additional requirements for the norm?

Comment: @Michael:  Yes, I want a norm $N$ such that it's restrcition to $\ell^2$ is finer than standard norm $N_2$ of $\ell^2$. I well edit my question.

Answer (score 8):

Pick a basis, and define the norm of a vector to be the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients of that vector in the basis.

For your extra requirement: Find a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ such that $U\oplus\ell^2=\mathbb R^\mathbb N$. Put on $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ the norm which is the sup of the norm of $\ell^2$ and any norm (constructed as in my first paragraph) on $U$. This restricts to the norm of $\ell^2$, of course.

Comment: "Pick a basis." Easier said than done. ;)

Comment: @ Grumpy Parsnip: Yes, want you say that  there is not an  explicit  basis, but there is one theoretically?

Comment: @Grumpy: It's actually quite easy. Much like picking up a tomato at the market. You don't have a concrete process, you just know a good one when you see it. Choosing a basis is not different, you just use the axiom of choice to recognize one. There's not explicit choice mechanism.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm just joking around. I actually own, and this is not a joke, a shirt that says "I believe the Axiom of Choice."

Comment: @Grumpy: This is awesome. I'd totally own a shirt saying "I believe the Axiom of Extensionality".

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the axiom of choice, yes.

Using the axiom of choice/Zorn's lemma/etc. you can choose $B$ to be a basis for the vector space. Now we define for $v$, if $v=\sum_{b\in B}\alpha_bb$, then $$\|v\|=\sum_{b\in B}|\alpha_b|.$$

It is not hard to check that this is indeed a norm.

If we do not assume the axiom of choice, then this becomes an open problem, and there is a long standing thread about this on this very site as it is.

Comment: There's a little problem there: $\Sigma|\alpha_b|$ doesn't have to converge.

Comment: @Michael, it is a finite sum

Comment: @Michael: By definition of a basis, all but finitely many $b\in B$ have $\alpha_b=0$.

Comment: Can you show that $B$ would be countable?

Comment: It is not countable.

Comment: @Michael: We can easily show that it is uncountable.

Comment: Since it's uncountable how would you make sense of $\Sigma_{b\in B}$?

Comment: As we remarked, the sum is **finite**. You should review the definition of what a basis of a vector space is.

Comment: @Michael: Again, all but finitely many $\alpha_b$ **MUST** be equal to $0$. So the sum is in fact a finite sum of non-zero real numbers.

Comment: @Michael : such a basis is often called a "Hamel basis".

Answer (score -1):

There is no norm on the **entire** $E=\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ (with the property that $||x||=0 \implies x=0$).

Suppose such norm exists. Let's denote the elements of $E$ as $a=(a_1,...,a_n,...)$ and suppose $||a_i||=\alpha_i>0$. Then form a vector $b=(b_1,...,b_n,...)$ such that $||b||=\infty$.

Here's how you do that: start with $b_1=2^1\frac{a_1}{||a_1||}$, then choose between $b_2=\pm 2^2\frac{a_2}{||a_2||}$, depending for which $b_2$ the norm is greater, etc. This would make the norm of $b$ unbounded.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Look at my answer of at Asaf's

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: that's what I'm trying to understand. My arguments seem to indicate that such norm doesn't exist; Asaf's arguments show it does. There ought to be a gap in one or another.

Comment: Well, there is a gap in yours. That was the point of my comment :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I would appreciate if you point to that gap.

Comment: Your construction of the vector $b$ does not make quite sense. What **exactly** do you mean by «depending for which $b_2$ the norm is greater»? The norm of what?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, depending on $||(b_1,...,b_{n-1},b_n,0,...)||>||(b_1,...,b_{n-1},-b_n,0,...)||$. This is, admittedly, hand-waving. If you are confident in Asaf's proof then never mind, I'll figure out why my intuition was wrong later.

Comment: It may well be the case that  you pick the $b$s so that, for example, $\Vert(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n,0,0,\dots)\Vert\geq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ yet $\Vert(b_1,b_2,\dots...)\Vert=1$.

Comment: There is no apriori connection between the norms of the "truncations" of a vector $(b_1,\dots)$ and the norm of the vector itself. Indeed, the set $S$ whose elements are the truncations of $v=(b_1,\dots)$ and $v$ itself is (provided all the $b_i$ are non-zero) is linearly independent. So there exist norms on $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ which take **arbitrary** values on the elements of $S$.

Comment: It seems that you do prove that there is no norm that preserves pointwise convergence, however.